# Select sum query does not work while implemented in a function/procedure

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

I came a cross a problem when using two sum() in a function called by a procedure. The results that are inputted came separate. The following tables, function and procedure is what I tried. P.S. - it works fine when there is a single sum(x).

```
 DROP TABLE MATCH;
    CREATE TABLE MATCH 
       (M_ID VARCHAR2 (4) NOT NULL,
        HT_ID VARCHAR2 (4),
        AT_ID VARCHAR2 (4),
        P_F NUMBER (3),
      P_A NUMBER (3));


INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M01','T1', 'T2',  2, 0);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M02','T1', 'T2',  1, 1);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M03','T1', 'T2',  0, 2);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M04','T1', 'T2', 0, 2);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M05','T2', 'T1', 2, 0);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M06','T2', 'T1',  0, 2);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M07','T2', 'T1',  1, 2);

INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
('M08','T2', 'T1',  0, 2);
```

Temp table (where the results will be stored):

```
DROP TABLE RESULTS;
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE RESULTS
(ht_id varchar2 (5),
 FINAL NUMBER (2))
 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

 insert into RESULTS values('T1', NULL);
 insert into RESULTS values('T2', NULL);
 insert into RESULTS values('T3', NULL);
 insert into RESULTS values('T4', NULL);
 insert into RESULTS values('T5', NULL);
```

**Query that I applied:**

```
select
sum(case when HT_ID='T1' then P_F else 0 end) +
sum(case when AT_ID='T1' then P_A else 0 end)
from match;
```

Returns the result of 9, I applied the select query in a function and made a procedure to call that function and store the results in a temp table. Although the result of the sum that was done in the function comes separate (e.g. 6 for T1 and 3 for T2, although 9 points should be for T1 alone).

```
HT_ID      FINAL
----- ----------
T1             3
T2             6
T3             0
T4             0
T5             0
```

How can I retain the same result as the query and input them into the temp table? **Like below:**

```
HT_ID      FINAL
----- ----------
T1             9
T2             0
T3             0
T4             0
T5             0
```

**This is what I tried in regards of function and procedure:**

```
 drop function RESULTSFINAL;
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RESULTSFINAL(i_HT_ID RESULTS.HT_ID%TYPE)

 RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS

 v_RESULTS_FINAL  RESULTS.FINAL%TYPE;


BEGIN
 select sum(case when HT_ID='T1' then P_F else 0 end)+ sum(case when AT_ID='T1' then    P_A else 0 end)
 INTO v_RESULTS_FINAL
 FROM MATCH
 WHERE HT_ID = i_HT_ID;

 IF v_RESULTS_FINAL IS NULL THEN
  v_RESULTS_FINAL := 0;
END IF;
RETURN v_RESULTS_FINAL;
END;
/
```

**The procedure:**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FINALSCORES
    AS

    CURSOR c_RESULTS
    IS

     SELECT HT_ID
     FROM RESULTS;


    v_HT_ID  RESULTS.HT_ID%TYPE;
    v_RESULTS_FINAL  RESULTS.FINAL%TYPE;

    BEGIN  

    OPEN c_RESULTS;

     LOOP

    FETCH c_RESULTS INTO v_HT_ID;

    EXIT WHEN c_RESULTS%NOTFOUND;

     v_RESULTS_FINAL := RESULTSFINAL(v_HT_ID);

     UPDATE RESULTS
     SET FINAL = v_RESULTS_FINAL
     WHERE HT_ID = v_HT_ID;


   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c_RESULTS;

   END;
    /
```

**Execute FINALSCORES;**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just remove line `WHERE HT_ID = i_HT_ID` from your function.

Comment: Could do that yes, but the result "9" will be placed in all the teams. It repeats it.

Comment: **UPDATE**  I have changed the select statement in the function with **select sum(case when HT_ID='T1' or HT_ID='T2' or HT_ID='T3' or HT_ID='T4' or HT_ID='T5' then P_F else 0 end)+ sum(case when AT_ID='T1'or AT_ID='T2' or AT_ID='T3' or AT_ID='T4' or AT_ID='T5' then P_A else 0 end)**
**Now** I get the results the way I want to but in the wrong order, the right points goes to the wrong team. Help please! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  sum(case when HT_ID=i_HT_ID then P_F else 0 end)
  + sum(case when AT_ID=i_HT_ID then P_A else 0 end)
INTO v_RESULTS_FINAL
FROM MATCH;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Egor! That is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform the same using DECODE as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RESULTSFINAL(i_HT_ID RESULTS.HT_ID%TYPE)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
IS

    v_RESULTS_FINAL  RESULTS.FINAL%TYPE;
BEGIN

      select sum(decode(HT_ID,i_HT_ID,P_F,
                              decode(AT_ID,i_HT_ID,P_A,0)))
                into v_RESULTS_FINAL
      from match;

      IF v_RESULTS_FINAL IS NULL THEN
          v_RESULTS_FINAL := 0;
      END IF;

      RETURN v_RESULTS_FINAL;
END;
/
```